# Untiy Cardboard SDK Black Border

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, google-cardboard

I was wondering if there is a way to show Google VR black border on stereo view inside the Unity Editor. Currently, it seems to be automatically created when compiled for mobile devices. But no way to have it in Editor or even in Desktop Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of the Cardboard SDK for Unity (v0.4.9) will do this.

Comment: Exact! Downloaded it but it appears they only do that for Editor and Android, not Desktop apps. I manage the code to make it works on Desktop (I mean I'm able to see the scene in stereo) but I've still haven't those beautiful Occulus-like black border. Do you have any tips ?

Comment: Do you mean the one with curved edges?  That is from the distortion shader.  You can add the RadialUndistortionEffect script to each of the Left and Right cameras to get that effect.

Comment: Also, make sure to turn off Cardboard.SDK.nativeDistortionCorrection, or RadialUndistortionEffect will not do anything.

Comment: Ok this works well (but you have to remove some code). thank you very much smd !!